# nutch hadoop only one slave is crawling

Tags: hadoop, fetch, nutch

I have a 3-slaves hadoop cluster and I am performing a crawl on a single website. However, only 1 slave is performing fetching (though the other slaves are still alive). Is this normal behavior if only 1 domain is crawled? Is there any way to force the other slaves to fetch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As part of any Hadoop MR job design there is a decision how to split the work between mappers.
In Your case nutch splits the fetching process by sites, and as a result only one mapper is used to fetch the data. If you hade more sites, it would split the load. 
Here is a good description of the process: How does Nutch work with Hadoop cluster?